# Too much unused style tags added to RTF text after being exported from word .dot to a .rtf

Tags: vba, templates, ms-word, richtextbox, rtf

I have a word template done with vba, and on a specific keyboard event I take changes done by user within document's BOOKMARKS to update them in DB.
The problem is that some data has to be saved with their styling (Bold, Italic, Colors, Alignment), but when I try to copy the content of a bookmark and get the rtf content of it, a lot of unnecessary tags are added!
I don't want the plain text, I want to keep the necessary style tags, but I have to remove the rest, because it is impossible for me to save all this data in DB, too huge!!

This is a sample of what I'm using and getting:
in a bookmark, it is written "***test1**" in Bold, when I take it as from a rich text box, what I get is the following string:

> "{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033\deflangfe1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0
>   Times New Roman;}{\f1\froman\fprq2\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}}
>   \viewkind4\uc1\pard\ltrpar\b\f0\fs24 ***test1**\b0\f1\par }"

but after I use my piece of code (that I have to use it), what I get is:

> "{\rtf1\adeflang1025\ansi\ansicpg1252\uc1\adeff31507\deff0\stshfdbch31505\stshfloch31506\stshfhich31506\stshfbi31507\deflang1033\deflangfe1033\themelang1033\themelangfe0\themelangcs0{\fonttbl{\f0\fbidi
>   \froman\fcharset0\fprq2{*\panose 02020603050405020304}Times New
>   Roman;}{\f34\fbidi \froman\fcharset0\fprq2{*\panose
>   02040503050406030204}Cambria Math;} {\f37\fbidi
>   \fswiss\fcharset0\fprq2{*\panose
>   020f0502020204030204}Calibri;}{\flomajor\f31500\fbidi
>   \froman\fcharset0\fprq2{*\panose 02020603050405020304}Times New
>   Roman;} {\fdbmajor\f31501\fbidi \froman\fcharset0\fprq2{*\panose
>   02020603050405020304}Times New Roman;}{\fhimajor\f31502\fbidi
>   \froman\fcharset0\fprq2{*\panose 02040503050406030204}Cambria;}
>   {\fbimajor\f31503\fbidi \froman\fcharset0\fprq2{*\panose
>   02020603050405020304}Times New Roman;}{\flominor\f31504\fbidi
>   \froman\fcharset0\fprq2{*\panose 02020603050405020304}Times New
>   Roman;} {\fdbminor\f31505\fbidi \froman\fcharset0\fprq2{*\panose
>   02020603050405020304}Times New Roman;}{\fhiminor\f31506\fbidi
>   \fswiss\fcharset0\fprq2{*\panose 020f0502020204030204}Calibri;}
>   {\fbiminor\f31507\fbidi \froman\fcharset0\fprq2{*\panose
>   02020603050405020304}Times New Roman;}{\f41\fbidi
>   \froman\fcharset238\fprq2 Times New Roman CE;}{\f42\fbidi
>   \froman\fcharset204\fprq2 Times New Roman Cyr;} {\f44\fbidi
>   \froman\fcharset161\fprq2 Times New Roman Greek;}{\f45\fbidi
>   \froman\fcharset162\fprq2 Times New Roman Tur;}{\f46\fbidi
>   \froman\fcharset177\fprq2 Times New Roman (Hebrew);}{\f47\fbidi
>   \froman\fcharset178\fprq2 Times New Roman (Arabic);} {\f48\fbidi
>   \froman\fcharset186\fprq2 Times New Roman Baltic;}{\f49\fbidi
>   \froman\fcharset163\fprq2 Times New Roman (Vietnamese);}{\f381\fbidi
>   \froman\fcharset238\fprq2 Cambria Math CE;}{\f382\fbidi
>   \froman\fcharset204\fprq2 Cambria Math Cyr;} {\f384\fbidi
>   \froman\fcharset161\fprq2 Cambria Math Greek;}{\f385\fbidi
>   \froman\fcharset162\fprq2 Cambria Math Tur;}{\f388\fbidi
>   \froman\fcharset186\fprq2 Cambria Math Baltic;}{\f389\fbidi
>   \froman\fcharset163\fprq2 Cambria Math (Vietnamese);} {\f411\fbidi
>   \fswiss\fcharset238\fprq2 Calibri CE;}{\f412\fbidi
>   \fswiss\fcharset204\fprq2 Calibri Cyr;}{\f414\fbidi
>   \fswiss\fcharset161\fprq2 Calibri Greek;}{\f415\fbidi
>   \fswiss\fcharset162\fprq2 Calibri Tur;} {\f418\fbidi
>   \fswiss\fcharset186\fprq2 Calibri Baltic;}{\f419\fbidi
>   \fswiss\fcharset163\fprq2 Calibri
>   (Vietnamese);}{\flomajor\f31508\fbidi \froman\fcharset238\fprq2 Times
>   New Roman CE;} {\flomajor\f31509\fbidi \froman\fcharset204\fprq2 Times
>   New Roman Cyr;}{\flomajor\f31511\fbidi \froman\fcharset161\fprq2 Times
>   New Roman Greek;}{\flomajor\f31512\fbidi \froman\fcharset162\fprq2
>   Times New Roman Tur;} {\flomajor\f31513\fbidi
>   \froman\fcharset177\fprq2 Times New Roman
>   (Hebrew);}{\flomajor\f31514\fbidi \froman\fcharset178\fprq2 Times New
>   Roman (Arabic);}{\flomajor\f31515\fbidi \froman\fcharset186\fprq2
>   Times New Roman Baltic;} {\flomajor\f31516\fbidi
>   \froman\fcharset163\fprq2 Times New Roman
>   (Vietnamese);}{\fdbmajor\f31518\fbidi \froman\fcharset238\fprq2 Times
>   New Roman CE;}{\fdbmajor\f31519\fbidi \froman\fcharset204\fprq2 Times
>   New Roman Cyr;} {\fdbmajor\f31521\fbidi \froman\fcharset161\fprq2
>   Times New Roman Greek;}{\fdbmajor\f31522\fbidi
>   \froman\fcharset162\fprq2 Times New Roman Tur;}{\fdbmajor\f31523\fbidi
>   \froman\fcharset177\fprq2 Times New Roman (Hebrew);}
>   {\fdbmajor\f31524\fbidi \froman\fcharset178\fprq2 Times New Roman
>   (Arabic);}{\fdbmajor\f31525\fbidi \froman\fcharset186\fprq2 Times New
>   Roman Baltic;}{\fdbmajor\f31526\fbidi \froman\fcharset163\fprq2 Times
>   New Roman (Vietnamese);} {\fhimajor\f31528\fbidi
>   \froman\fcharset238\fprq2 Cambria CE;}{\fhimajor\f31529\fbidi
>   \froman\fcharset204\fprq2 Cambria Cyr;}{\fhimajor\f31531\fbidi
>   \froman\fcharset161\fprq2 Cambria Greek;}{\fhimajor\f31532\fbidi
>   \froman\fcharset162\fprq2 Cambria Tur;} {\fhimajor\f31535\fbidi
>   \froman\fcharset186\fprq2 Cambria Baltic;}{\fhimajor\f31536\fbidi
>   \froman\fcharset163\fprq2 Cambria
>   (Vietnamese);}{\fbimajor\f31538\fbidi \froman\fcharset238\fprq2 Times
>   New Roman CE;} {\fbimajor\f31539\fbidi \froman\fcharset204\fprq2 Times
>   New Roman Cyr;}{\fbimajor\f31541\fbidi \froman\fcharset161\fprq2 Times
>   New Roman Greek;}{\fbimajor\f31542\fbidi \froman\fcharset162\fprq2
>   Times New Roman Tur;} {\fbimajor\f31543\fbidi
>   \froman\fcharset177\fprq2 Times New Roman
>   (Hebrew);}{\fbimajor\f31544\fbidi \froman\fcharset178\fprq2 Times New
>   Roman (Arabic);}{\fbimajor\f31545\fbidi \froman\fcharset186\fprq2
>   Times New Roman Baltic;} {\fbimajor\f31546\fbidi
>   \froman\fcharset163\fprq2 Times New Roman
>   (Vietnamese);}{\flominor\f31548\fbidi \froman\fcharset238\fprq2 Times
>   New Roman CE;}{\flominor\f31549\fbidi \froman\fcharset204\fprq2 Times
>   New Roman Cyr;} {\flominor\f31551\fbidi \froman\fcharset161\fprq2
>   Times New Roman Greek;}{\flominor\f31552\fbidi
>   \froman\fcharset162\fprq2 Times New Roman Tur;}{\flominor\f31553\fbidi
>   \froman\fcharset177\fprq2 Times New Roman (Hebrew);}
>   {\flominor\f31554\fbidi \froman\fcharset178\fprq2 Times New Roman
>   (Arabic);}{\flominor\f31555\fbidi \froman\fcharset186\fprq2 Times New
>   Roman Baltic;}{\flominor\f31556\fbidi \froman\fcharset163\fprq2 Times
>   New Roman (Vietnamese);} {\fdbminor\f31558\fbidi
>   \froman\fcharset238\fprq2 Times New Roman CE;}{\fdbminor\f31559\fbidi
>   \froman\fcharset204\fprq2 Times New Roman Cyr;}{\fdbminor\f31561\fbidi
>   \froman\fcharset161\fprq2 Times New Roman Greek;}
>   {\fdbminor\f31562\fbidi \froman\fcharset162\fprq2 Times New Roman
>   Tur;}{\fdbminor\f31563\fbidi \froman\fcharset177\fprq2 Times New Roman
>   (Hebrew);}{\fdbminor\f31564\fbidi \froman\fcharset178\fprq2 Times New
>   Roman (Arabic);} {\fdbminor\f31565\fbidi \froman\fcharset186\fprq2
>   Times New Roman Baltic;}{\fdbminor\f31566\fbidi
>   \froman\fcharset163\fprq2 Times New Roman
>   (Vietnamese);}{\fhiminor\f31568\fbidi \fswiss\fcharset238\fprq2
>   Calibri CE;} {\fhiminor\f31569\fbidi \fswiss\fcharset204\fprq2 Calibri
>   Cyr;}{\fhiminor\f31571\fbidi \fswiss\fcharset161\fprq2 Calibri
>   Greek;}{\fhiminor\f31572\fbidi \fswiss\fcharset162\fprq2 Calibri Tur;}
>   {\fhiminor\f31575\fbidi \fswiss\fcharset186\fprq2 Calibri
>   Baltic;}{\fhiminor\f31576\fbidi \fswiss\fcharset163\fprq2 Calibri
>   (Vietnamese);}{\fbiminor\f31578\fbidi \froman\fcharset238\fprq2 Times
>   New Roman CE;} {\fbiminor\f31579\fbidi \froman\fcharset204\fprq2 Times
>   New Roman Cyr;}{\fbiminor\f31581\fbidi \froman\fcharset161\fprq2 Times
>   New Roman Greek;}{\fbiminor\f31582\fbidi \froman\fcharset162\fprq2
>   Times New Roman Tur;} {\fbiminor\f31583\fbidi
>   \froman\fcharset177\fprq2 Times New Roman
>   (Hebrew);}{\fbiminor\f31584\fbidi \froman\fcharset178\fprq2 Times New
>   Roman (Arabic);}{\fbiminor\f31585\fbidi \froman\fcharset186\fprq2
>   Times New Roman Baltic;} {\fbiminor\f31586\fbidi
>   \froman\fcharset163\fprq2 Times New Roman
>   (Vietnamese);}}{\colortbl;\red0\green0\blue0;\red0\green0\blue255;\red0\green255\blue255;\red0\green255\blue0;\red255\green0\blue255;\red255\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue0;
>   \red255\green255\blue255;\red0\green0\blue128;\red0\green128\blue128;\red0\green128\blue0;\red128\green0\blue128;\red128\green0\blue0;\red128\green128\blue0;\red128\green128\blue128;\red192\green192\blue192;}{*\defchp
>   \fs22\loch\af31506\hich\af31506\dbch\af31505 }{*\defpap \ql
>   \li0\ri0\sa200\sl276\slmult1\widctlpar\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0
>   }\noqfpromote {\stylesheet{\ql \li0\ri0\sa200\sl276\slmult1
>   \widctlpar\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0
>   \rtlch\fcs1 \af31507\afs22\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0
>   \fs22\lang1033\langfe1033\loch\f31506\hich\af31506\dbch\af31505\cgrid\langnp1033\langfenp1033
>   \snext0 \sqformat \spriority0 Normal;} {*\cs10 \additive \ssemihidden
>   \sunhideused \spriority1 Default Paragraph Font;}{*
>   \ts11\tsrowd\trftsWidthB3\trpaddl108\trpaddr108\trpaddfl3\trpaddft3\trpaddfb3\trpaddfr3\tblind0\tblindtype3\tsvertalt\tsbrdrt\tsbrdrl\tsbrdrb\tsbrdrr\tsbrdrdgl\tsbrdrdgr\tsbrdrh\tsbrdrv
>   \ql \li0\ri0\sa200\sl276\slmult1
>   \widctlpar\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0
>   \rtlch\fcs1 \af31507\afs22\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0
>   \fs22\lang1033\langfe1033\loch\f31506\hich\af31506\dbch\af31505\cgrid\langnp1033\langfenp1033
>   \snext11 \ssemihidden \sunhideused  Normal Table;}}{*\rsidtbl
>   \rsid664789\rsid11549567}{\mmathPr\mmathFont34\mbrkBin0\mbrkBinSub0\msmallFrac0\mdispDef1\mlMargin0\mrMargin0\mdefJc1\mwrapIndent1440\mintLim0\mnaryLim1}{\info{\version0}{\edmins0}{\nofpages1}{\nofwords0}{\nofchars6}
>   {*\company OSD}{\nofcharsws6}{\vern49167}}{*\xmlnstbl {\xmlns1
>   http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml}}\paperw12240\paperh15840\margl1440\margr1440\margt1440\margb1440\gutter0\ltrsect
>   \widowctrl\ftnbj\aenddoc\trackmoves0\trackformatting1\donotembedsysfont1\relyonvml0\donotembedlingdata0\grfdocevents0\validatexml1\showplaceholdtext0\ignoremixedcontent0\saveinvalidxml0\showxmlerrors1\noxlattoyen
>   \expshrtn\noultrlspc\dntblnsbdb\nospaceforul\formshade\horzdoc\dgmargin\dghspace180\dgvspace180\dghorigin1701\dgvorigin1984\dghshow1\dgvshow1
>   \jexpand\pgbrdrhead\pgbrdrfoot\splytwnine\ftnlytwnine\htmautsp\nolnhtadjtbl\useltbaln\alntblind\lytcalctblwd\lyttblrtgr\lnbrkrule\nobrkwrptbl\snaptogridincell\allowfieldendsel\wrppunct\asianbrkrule\rsidroot664789
>   \newtblstyruls\nogrowautofit\usenormstyforlist\noindnmbrts\felnbrelev\nocxsptable\indrlsweleven\noafcnsttbl\afelev\utinl\hwelev\spltpgpar\notcvasp\notbrkcnstfrctbl\notvatxbx\krnprsnet\cachedcolbal
>   \nouicompat \fet0{*\wgrffmtfilter 2450}
>   \nofeaturethrottle1\ilfomacatclnup0\ltrpar \sectd
>   \ltrsect\linex0\endnhere\sectlinegrid360\sectdefaultcl\sftnbj
>   {*\pnseclvl1\pnucrm\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxta
>   .}}{*\pnseclvl2\pnucltr\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxta
>   .}}{*\pnseclvl3 \pndec\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxta
>   .}}{*\pnseclvl4\pnlcltr\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxta
>   )}}{*\pnseclvl5\pndec\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxtb (}{\pntxta
>   )}}{*\pnseclvl6\pnlcltr\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxtb
>   (}{\pntxta )}} {*\pnseclvl7\pnlcrm\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang
>   {\pntxtb (}{\pntxta
>   )}}{*\pnseclvl8\pnlcltr\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxtb
>   (}{\pntxta )}}{*\pnseclvl9\pnlcrm\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang
>   {\pntxtb (}{\pntxta )}}\pard\plain \ltrpar \ql
>   \li0\ri0\sa200\sl276\slmult1\widctlpar\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0
>   \rtlch\fcs1 \af31507\afs22\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0
>   \fs22\lang1033\langfe1033\loch\af31506\hich\af31506\dbch\af31505\cgrid\langnp1033\langfenp1033
>   { \rtlch\fcs1 \ab\af0\afs24 \ltrch\fcs0
>   \b\f0\fs24\insrsid664789\charrsid15300069
>   \hich\af0\dbch\af31505\loch\f0 ***test1**}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af31507
>   \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid11549567  \par }{*\themedata
>   504b030414000600080000002100e9de0fbfff0000001c020000130000005b436f6e74656e745f54797065735d2e786d6cac91cb4ec3301045f748fc83e52d4a
>   ..."

and much more

As you can see, too much unused information.

```
Sub Test()
Dim ad As Document
Set ad = ActiveDocument
Dim bm As Bookmark
dim rtf as String

For Each bm In ad.Bookmarks
    Set rngread = bm.Range
    rngread.End = rngread.End - 1 'for the 1 font space protecting the bookmark
    rtf = GetRTFtext(rngread)
Next
End Sub

Function GetRTFtext(rngread As Range) As String
    Dim RTFText As String
    Dim TempFile As String

    TempFile = "C:/Temp/tmp0859" & Day(Now) & Month(Now) & Year(Now) & Hour(Now) & Minute(Now) & Second(Now) & ".rtf"
    rngread.ExportFragment TempFile, wdFormatRTF
    Dim objFSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim objTextStream As TextStream
    Set objTextStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(TempFile, ForReading)
    RTFText = objTextStream.ReadAll
    objTextStream.Close
    If objFSO.FileExists(TempFile) Then objFSO.DeleteFile TempFile
    GetRTFtext = RTFText
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word adds a lot of useless data. To minimize the rtf, load it into a temp richtext box and then read its `RTF` propety.

```
rtbTemp.RTF ="..."
```

Then read `rtbTEmp.RTF`